# Right align icons inside Bulma navbar-dropdown

Tags: bulma

What is the correct way to *right align* icons inside a [Bulma](https://bulma.io/) `navbar-dropdown`?

I have created [this Codepen](https://codepen.io/dukedave/pen/WBWbMM) based on [the docs](https://bulma.io/documentation/components/navbar/#basic-navbar):

```
<nav class="navbar" role="navigation" aria-label="main navigation">
  <div class="navbar-item has-dropdown is-hoverable">
    <a class="navbar-link">
      More
    </a>

    <div class="navbar-dropdown">
      <a class="navbar-item">
        About
        <span class="icon">
          <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
        </span>       
      </a>
      <a class="navbar-item">
        Jobs
        <span class="icon">
          <i class="fas fa-briefcase"></i>
        </span>       
      </a>
      <a class="navbar-item">
        Contact
        <span class="icon">
          <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
        </span>       
      </a>
      <hr class="navbar-divider">
      <a class="navbar-item">
        Report an issue
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

but I can't get the icons to move to the right, thus:

[image: icons on left, arrows point to right]

Comment: I would have thought you would know better than to ask a question without supplying the code within your question and I wouldn't have to link you to [mcve]

Comment: It's posted in the codepen

Comment: @Rob I have copied the HTML out of the codepen and put it inline in the question.

Comment: @jdgray Code, errors and other output are to be placed **within the question** and not any third party site: [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to want to use Bulma's [level](https://bulma.io/documentation/layout/level/) for what you are trying to accomplish. This was the only way I was able to get it working with the addition of one piece of custom CSS.

Here is what a sample `navbar-item` will look like:

```
<a class="navbar-item">
  <div class="level is-mobile">
    <div class="level-left">
      <span class="level-item">About</span>
    </div>
   <div class="level-right">
     <span class="icon level-item">
       <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
     </span>      
   </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

Notice the structure of the `level` class and then using `level-left` and `left-right` as child classes. Also something to note is that I used the [`is-mobile`](https://bulma.io/documentation/columns/responsiveness/#mobile-columns) class for a mobile friendly view (right aligned icons). You can also edit the default `navbar-item`'s `padding-right` to align the icon's more to the right. The last step is to increase the default width of the `level` class by doing:

```
.level {
  width: 100%;
}
```

I have updated your Codepen with a working [example](https://codepen.io/jd-gray/pen/XLWvQM).

Desktop View:

[image]

Mobile View:

[image]